# GameKit, GKGameSession how to add players to the session and send data?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit, gkgamesession

I created a session, shared it to another player and now I want to start a game.
I can see a session with two players on both devices. So, it looks like we're ready to game but I need to change connected status before the game and I can do this on both devices.

But... when I do this on device A, I see that user A is connected and user B isn't. And after that, when I repeat the process on device B, I see vice versa situation. B is connected and A is not.

Here is my code that connect player and send the data:

```
session.setConnectionState(.connected) { (error) in
   if let err = error {
      assertionFailure(err.localizedDescription)
   }
   else {

      print("NC:",session.players(with: .notConnected))
      print(" C:",session.players(with: .connected))
            
      let m = MoveTransfer(move:1) // test struct to send/receive data
        
      session.send(m.data(), with: .reliable) { (error) in
         if let err = error {
            assertionFailure(err.localizedDescription)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm getting error:

`The requested operation could not be completed because there are no recipients connected to the session`

By the way, I'm unable to change connected state on the simulator (iCloud is logged in).

I forgot to mention, that I'm working on a turn based game.

#### Edit

Tried again and now after several iterations I got this:

I have both players connected to session. But send data still doesn't work.

here is console output:

```
NC: [] // not connected array and connected array below
C: [<GKCloudPlayer: 0x17402e700>, id: playerID1, name: Player1,<GKCloudPlayer: 0x17402e900>, id: playerID2, name: Player2]

fatal error: The requested operation could not be completed because there are no recipients connected to the session.
```

Got this on two real devices.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send data and receive it on the other device. I used loadSessions function to load all session (I think that loadSession by id would do the trick too).
I did the following, D1 is a device 1 and D2 device 2:

```
1. D1: load all sessions and set player state to connected
2. D2: load all sessions and set player state to connected
3. D1: load all sessions again and set player state to connected
4. D1 || D2: send data
5. D2 || D1: data 256 bytes from player: <GKCloudPlayer: 0x1c022b380>, id: playerID, name: (null)
```

Although, I wasn't able to transfer data back and forth on both devices since if we'll add step 6. that sends data from device that just received it, we'll get an error: `The requested operation could not be completed because there are no recipients connected to the session`.

I do not sure what is the reason of it but I stop my efforts on this stage, since I think now, that I don't need to be connected to session to play turn based game.

I found this "new" iOS 10 APIs abandoned. By Apple and by devs consequently. If you one of those who still trying to use it drop me a note at my twitter (link in my bio) if you want to discuss GKGameSession and related topics.